# TinyMCE imagetools_toolbar position

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce, toolbar

How do I show the imagetools toolbar always on top of an image? As an example, this adds various options to the toolbar: `imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph",` but I am not sure if there's a command that allows to show the toolbar always on top. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image tools toolbar does not have an option to appear on top of the image at all times.  As with several of the context-sensitive toolbars they only appear when you click on the appropriate element (e.g. tables and images).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that the toolbar does appear at the top when there's no space at the bottom (when the image height is larger than the editor's height. So somewhere in the code it does make it go to the top. I am just wondering if it's possible to do the same using CSS.

Comment: There is nothing you can do configuration-wise to change this behavior.  As TinyMCE is open source you could try to modify our code to change this behavior but it is designed to put the toolbar where it is visible based on where the image appears within the viewport.